# multiple libraries, is it possible to retreive in CSWP or similar the files checked out?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, content-search-web-part, check-out

In a multiple libraries scenario (400+ in the same site) of files with a content type, I would like to retrieve the elements that are checked out to someone (not a specific person).

I am trying to use a CSWP and I have placed the Checkoutuser in a refinable string.

Can anybody suggest if it is possible to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

First map crawl to refinable and then start incremental or full crawl.

Test this solution
https://afrait.com/blog/display-all-checked-out-files-from-current-user-en/

In query you set Checkoutuser isnotblank and that content type

### EDIT

I found it :)
https://ktnnsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/search-checkedout-files/

You need to place that managed property in query like this to get all documents that are checkout.

```
CheckoutUserOWSUSER:a* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:b* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:c* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:d* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:e* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:f* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:g* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:h* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:i* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:j* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:k* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:l* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:m* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:n* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:o* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:p* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:q* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:r* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:s* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:t* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:u* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:v* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:w* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:x* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:y* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:z* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:1* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:2* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:3* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:4* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:5* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:6* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:7* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:8* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:9* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:0*
```

Comment: it does not work in sharepoint online

Comment: You could force reindex one list in list settings >advanced settings>reindex this list

Comment: the procedure partially works, the problems is that of all the checked out files it brings up only mine even tho I wrote user.name.

Comment: Secondly this does not work at all when you have a mandatory metadata scenario and the reason why it is not checked in is because metadata is missing, in this case it does not find anything and it is not a matter of indexing

Comment: To return all files you don't need to set user.name, you need to check if Checkoutuser is not blank.

Comment: which is translated as value:{user.name}

Comment: Look edited answer